# How can I declare a global variable in LLVM?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I'd like to record some dynamic behaviors into some global variables. So I wrote a pass to instrument the code and insert some instructions to update the global variable. I tried to use the GlobalVariable constructor to define a global variable, but there are two problems. First, how can I DEFINE the global variables in the module containing main function? Second, how can I DECLARE those global variables in other modules? It's like "extern double someThing;".

The target programs are written in C.

Comment: What language are you using?  ([LLVM](http://llvm.org/) is not a language, it's "a collection of modular and reusable compiler and toolchain technologies").

Comment: It sounds like they're using the LLVM API to construct programs directly, rather than via compiling a language.

Comment: Yes, I just want to insert several instructions.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is a tool which can answer this and many other questions about LLVM API: `llc -march=cpp`. You can generate a bitcode file using Clang or llvm-gcc, and then build a C++ code which should reconstruct the same module using the `cpp` backend.

A sample output, showing how to define a global `int *` variable:

```c++
// Global Variable Declarations

GlobalVariable* gvar_ptr_abc = new GlobalVariable(/*Module=*/*mod, 
        /*Type=*/PointerTy_0,
        /*isConstant=*/false,
        /*Linkage=*/GlobalValue::CommonLinkage,
        /*Initializer=*/0, // has initializer, specified below
        /*Name=*/"abc");
gvar_ptr_abc->setAlignment(4);

// Constant Definitions
ConstantPointerNull* const_ptr_2 = ConstantPointerNull::get(PointerTy_0);

// Global Variable Definitions
gvar_ptr_abc->setInitializer(const_ptr_2);
```

Comment: That looks like C++, not C (the `ConstantPointerNull::get()` call).

Comment: @Keith Thompson, you can't write an LLVM pass in C anyway, so what's the problem?

Comment: The OP said the target programs are written in C.  (I'm not familiar with LLVM, so I won't comment further.)

Comment: Thanks for answering part of the question. Can you explain a bit on the use of "CommonLinkage" rather than "ExternalLinkage"? I guess this piece of code implies that I should use the constructor to both declare and define a global variable. The only difference is that for declaration I set the initializer to 0?

Comment: @dalibocai, you'll use `ExternalLinkage` in the module where you're declaring an external variable. This one is a *definition* (see the initialiser).

Comment: Update to anyone who sees this -- don't bother trying the C++ backend, [it doesn't exist anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751403/generate-llvm-c-api-code-as-backend).

Comment: Is there a reason to initialize it afterwards, rather than just create the constant first and pass directly as initializer?