# Generate LLVM C++ API code as backend

Tags: c++, linux, llvm, x86-64

The [Online LLVM demo](http://llvm.org/demo/) page had an option to generate LLVM C++ API code as backend from a source code. However, that demo page is now disabled. I was wondering how we can do it ourselves using the available LLVM tools.

I tried the following

```
clang++ -c -emit-llvm input.cpp -o input.ll
llc -march=cpp -o input.ll.cpp input.ll
```

which gives the following error

```
llc: error: invalid target 'cpp'.
```

I am using LLVM/Clang version 3.2.

Comment: does `llc -version` list `cpp` as a valid backend target?

Comment: llc -version does not show cpp on the list either. Does it require any registration or something to include cpp, or what?

Comment: @MetallicPriest I guess they just don't enable it for the online demo (it's not really what people are interested in, I guess) Why don't you install LLVM on your system locally?

Comment: If its not in the list, then its been removed as a backend, IMO you'd get a lot better help from the LLVM/CFE mailing lists.

Comment: How have you compiled LLVM? If I remember correctly, cpp backend is disabled by default in cmake-based systems. So, make sure it's enabled while configuring.

Comment: My llc here (llvm-3.1-12.fc18.x86_64, Fedora 18) does show cpp as a backend.

Comment: If you're still interested, my demo page at http://ellcc.org/demo/ can generate the C++ API code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<strike>The LLVM C++ backend has to be enabled during configuration when building LLVM. It's enabled by default in the `configure` (autotools) build, but not in the CMake build when you build on Windows. You can enable it by setting the appropriate flags while configuring with CMake. See [this page](http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html) for more information.</strike>

Quote:

> **LLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD:STRING**
>       Semicolon-separated list of targets to build, or all for building all targets. Case-sensitive. For Visual C++ defaults to X86. On the
>   other cases defaults to all. Example:
>   -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86;PowerPC".

**UPDATE**

Since `version 3.9` the CppBackend is no more a valid target. They've removed from their code as the generated code were presenting a few issues.

[Check this commit](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/commit/257fabb18605265a79397d35dd79a3973760ffaf)

```
Remove bit-rotten CppBackend.

This backend was supposed to generate C++ code which will re-construct
the LLVM IR passed as input. This seems to me to have very marginal
usefulness in the first place.

However, the code has never been updated to use IRBuilder, which makes
its current value negative -- people who look at the output may be
steered to use the *wrong* C++ APIs to construct IR.

Furthermore, it's generated code that doesn't compile since at least
2013.

Differential Revision: http://reviews.llvm.org/D19942

git-svn-id: https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk@268631 91177308-0d34-0410-b5e6-96231b3b80d8
```

Comment: Is there an alternative for the deprecated CppBackend in recent LLVM versions? Basically, something that would provide the same functionality, probably using IRBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, this appears to no longer be possible in more recent versions of LLVM. The associated commit message explains it pretty well.

As you can see in the following commit, 
[Remove bit-rotten CppBackend](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/commit/257fabb18605265a79397d35dd79a3973760ffaf), the generated code would show issues.

```
commit 257fabb18605265a79397d35dd79a3973760ffaf
Author: ---
Date:   Thu May 5 14:35:40 2016 +0000

Remove bit-rotten CppBackend.

This backend was supposed to generate C++ code which will re-construct
the LLVM IR passed as input. This seems to me to have very marginal
usefulness in the first place.

However, the code has never been updated to use IRBuilder, which makes
its current value negative -- people who look at the output may be
steered to use the *wrong* C++ APIs to construct IR.

Furthermore, it's generated code that doesn't compile since at least
2013.

Differential Revision: http://reviews.llvm.org/D19942

git-svn-id: https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk@268631 91177308-0d34-0410-b5e6-96231b3b80d8
```