# Define new type in LLVM

Tags: types, llvm, llvm-ir

In a very simple LLVM IR program, I can do

```
%MyStruct = type { i32 }
%MyInt = type i32

declare void @main(%MyStruct, %MyInt)
```

However, I cannot work out how to produce the same `%MyStruct = type { i32 }` or `%MyInt = type i32` statement using the LLVM C++ API. I've been scouring the docs for the past few days and the only thing I've found which is close to what I want is manually defining a new type as mentioned here: http://llvm.org/docs/ExtendingLLVM.html#adding-a-new-type

However, I would like a way to define and use new types using the LLVM C++ API, as I can with functions, etc.

The only other way I can think of doing this is keeping a separate record of my custom types and their LLVM primitive base type, and when declaring functions, use the primitive base type; but I didn't want to start doing that if there was a quicker way built into LLVM itself (as I discovered by looking at some LLVM IR examples and producing the code above).

**Edit:** I have done some more looking around, and I've found a reference to a function which appears to be exactly what I need called `addTypeName` in http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html and also in http://llvm.org/doxygen/Module_8h-source.html, however this appears to be all there is as I cannot see any reference to `addTypeName` in the actual documentation and I cannot compile a program using `addTypeName` as it claims the method does not exist.

Comment: `addTypeName` was removed in 3.0 as a consequence of the [type system rewrite](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/11/llvm-30-type-system-rewrite.html); as a result, it's no longer possible to name non-struct types. Whether this is a bug or not, I'm not sure.

Comment: Just tried compiling a `%foo = type i32` + a short function using `%foo` with `-march=cpp`: the generated API calls use IntegerType directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way for you is to use cpp backend (llc -march=cpp) - given the IR it will generate the sequence of C++ API calls necessary to reproduce the IR.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I did that and it helped to explain how the `llvm-as` works. For `MyStruct` it created a named `StructType`, which makes sense, but for `MyInt` it simply bypassed the naming of a new type and defines a function with `i32` as the parameter.

Comment: Sorry, I know this answer is old, but I have to downvote. All LLVM questions could be answered like this. Futher, I don't think the `-march=cpp` is available anymore: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751403/generate-llvm-c-api-code-as-backend