# LLVM IR String Initialization

Tags: string, llvm

I'm working on a program in LLVM IR, and I am trying to initialize a string that says "Hello World!" but I can't figure out how.  The goal of the code is to count the number of characters in the string.  Before the string needs to be initialized, and after the headers, I have the following:

```cpp
int main (int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    //Setting up 
    //Build a pointer to the string - LLVMValueRef *strptr=LLVMBuildGlobalStringPtr(builder, const char *string, const char *name);
    LLVMValueRef *strptr;
    LLVMContextRef context = LLVMContextCreate();
    LLVMBuilderRef builder = LLVMCreateBuilderInContext (context);
    LLVMModuleRef module1 = LLVMModuleCreateWithNameInContext("mod", context);
}
```

Comment: What do you can't figure out? I don't know much about this, but I'd say the first `char *` is the content (here `Hello World`), and the second one something like an variable name

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work.  I don't even know if I should be building a pointer to the string or if I need to make the string a global variable then store it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way to see how such things are by using the C++ backend - it generates the C++ API calls that build the module for you. You can see this done [online](http://ellcc.org/demo/index.cgi).

"Compile" this code:

```cpp
const char* foo() {
  const char* s = "hello world";
  return s;
}
```

And here are the relevant C++ API calls:

```cpp
GlobalVariable* gvar_array__str = new GlobalVariable(/*Module=*/*mod, 
 /*Type=*/ArrayTy_0,
 /*isConstant=*/true,
 /*Linkage=*/GlobalValue::PrivateLinkage,
 /*Initializer=*/0, // has initializer, specified below
 /*Name=*/".str");
 gvar_array__str->setAlignment(1);

 // Constant Definitions
 Constant *const_array_4 = ConstantDataArray::getString(mod->getContext(), "hello world", true);
 std::vector<Constant*> const_ptr_5_indices;
 ConstantInt* const_int64_6 = ConstantInt::get(mod->getContext(), APInt(64, StringRef("0"), 10));
 const_ptr_5_indices.push_back(const_int64_6);
 const_ptr_5_indices.push_back(const_int64_6);
 Constant* const_ptr_5 = ConstantExpr::getGetElementPtr(gvar_array__str, const_ptr_5_indices);

 // Global Variable Definitions
 gvar_array__str->setInitializer(const_array_4);

 // Function Definitions

 // Function: foo (func_foo)
 {

  BasicBlock* label_entry = BasicBlock::Create(mod->getContext(), "entry",func_foo,0);

  // Block entry (label_entry)
  ReturnInst::Create(mod->getContext(), const_ptr_5, label_entry);

 }
```

Comment: Update to anyone who sees this -- don't bother trying the C++ backend, [it doesn't exist anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751403/generate-llvm-c-api-code-as-backend).

Comment: @tonysdg  do you know any other way to show "how to use c/c++api generate IR"? I felt there is not enough document for those APIs. I don't bother use older version llvm and guess how the new version llvm works.

Comment: @worldterminator Sorry, I haven't been working with LLVM for over a year now. Best of luck!!

Comment: @tonysdg Pretty sure the C++ backend still exists - you just can't generate C++ code with LLVM API calls anymore.

Comment: To be clear for anyone reading this, @tonysdg is not referring to the C++ API and LLVM Core when he says the C++ backend does not exist anymore. They are still primary focuses of the LLVM project and continue to receive updates and new features. What he is referring to is a confusingly named feature where you could compile the code into LLVM C++ backend API calls. So in this answer, the second code block was generated by the tool which no longer exists. It was removed since it was not being kept up to date with changes to LLVM's C++ API and often generated misleading/deprecated/incorrect code.